# Prove that if $f$ is bijection map if and only if $f^{-1}$ is also bijection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

$\Rightarrow$
  Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be bijection map. Then, if $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ then $a_1=a_2$ for all $a_1$,$a_2$ in $A$ and sice $f$ is onto there is a $b$ in $B$ such that for all $a$ in $A$ implies $f(a)=b$. We need to show that $f^{-1}$ is also bijection but **how can I show, can you help?**

**And, can you check my introduction of proof (mathematical, english gramer etc.)?**

Comment: First show $f^{-1} $ is a well defined function.  That is for every $x\B $ that there is always exactly one $y_x\in A$ so that $f (y_x)=x $, so $f^{-1}(x)=y_x $ is welldefined.  Once you do that proving $f^{-1} $ is a bijection is trivial and direct from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is surjective.  So If $k,j\in B $ there are $k',j'\in A $ so that $f (k')=f(j') $. And $f ^{-1}(k)=k';f^{-1}(j)=j'$  As $f $ is injective  $f ^{-1}(k)=k'=f^{-1}(j)=j'$ if and only if $f (k')=k=j=f (j') $.  So $f^{-1}$ is injective.

If $k \in A $ then $f(k)\in B $ and so $j=f (k) $ exists.  And $f^{-1}(j)=f^{-1}(f (k))=k $.  So $f^{-1} $ is surjective.